# How to update textview declared in OnViewCreated from another function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I am trying to update the `TextView` of my fragment in Kotlin. How would I be able to update it while having the `TextView` declared in the `onViewCreated` of my fragment?

Inside `onViewCreated` function:

```
val txt = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txt) as TextView
```

In another function:

```
fun update(){
    txt.text= "Hello"
}
```

Comment: can you share the fragment code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't access it if its declared inside the onCreateView()

instead, try this in class level.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(){

   lateinit var txt: TextView

}
```

then assign your textView to the variable.

Although I have 2 suggestions for you:

1. Do not instantiate views inside onCreateView() try using onViewCreated() to instantiate.
2. use kotlin extensions or databinding to access views it saves a whole lot of trouble and actually easier to use.

Comment: Its inside onViewCreated()

Comment: Is that the best way to do it? Thanks I would like to know the best way.

Comment: 1. Google recommends using DataBinding. that has no view reference in your fragment or activity instead inside XML. the view is dynamically updated whenever data is changed by observing **live data**.

Comment: 2. Many developers & I personally like the Kotlin extensions they are easy to learn and use. have a look at this article ( https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try data binding

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by using Manzur Alahi's suggestion. Instead of using `findViewById` to get the `TextView`, I added the plugin that directly accesses the `TextView` without using `findViewById`. You can learn more about it here: https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

Updated code (No need to declare anything in `OnViewCreated`) :

```
fun update(){
Textview.txt="It works"
}
```